# Using Eulers equation to find General Solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, euler-product

I have the problem $y''+4y = 0$ where $y(0) = 1$ , and $y'(0) = 0$

I have to find a particular solution, making a guess it is in the form $y(x) = e^{rx}$

I have the solution here, but I cannot quite follow it.  I get that the Euler equation is $r^2 + 4 = 0$; and that $r = \pm2i$.  However, they show that Euler's equations suggest $e^{2ix} = \cos 2x + i  \sin 2x$.  Immediately followed by the solutions statement that $y(x) = c_1 \cos 2x + c_2 \sin 2x$.  How did they make this transition?

Then they state, to find the particular solution; we want $0=y(0) - c_1$ ; and $0 = y'(0) = 2c_2$.  Why is this the case?  Why do we want $y'(0)$ to be equal to $2c_2$?

The final particular solution is $y(x) = \cos 2x$.  This makes sense if $0 = 2c_2$ as they expressed above.  However, I still do not know same of those intermediate steps

Comment: did you forget something after the equals in your question? Regards

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

You need to fix the original, but here are the latter parts.

For the complex exponentials, refer to [*Complex Roots*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/ComplexRoots.aspx).

Do you follow this web site?

This gets us to the point of: $y(x) = c_1 \cos 2x + c_2 \sin 2x$

Next, we have been given initial conditions and will use those to find the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$.

If we substitute $0$ into $y(x)$, we have: $y(0) = 1 = c_1$, so $c_1 = 1$.

If we take the derivative of the solution, $y(x)$, we have:

$$y'(x) = -2c_1 \sin 2x + 2 c_2 \cos 2x$$

We know that $y'(0) = 0$, so we have (just substitute $x=0$ into the derivative), 
$y'(0) = 0 = 2 c_2$, which gives us $c_2 = 0$.

Substituting $c_1$ and $c_2$ into $y(x)$, yields the final solution:

$$y(x) = \cos 2x$$

You should validate that this indeed solves the DEQ.

$$y''(x) + 4y(x) = -4 \cos 2x + 4 \cos 2x = 0$$

Which checks out.

Regards

Comment: I would do the same if i was supposed to do this work. +

Comment: Nice work, Amzoti. I agree with Babak!

Answer (score 0):

To solve the linear homogeneous differential equation 
$$
y'' + 4y = 0,
$$
we find the solutions to its characteristic equation, which, as you said, is
$$
r^2 + 4 = 0,
$$
which gives the result $r=\pm2i$. Using this result, the linear superposition principle, which gives us $y(x) = e^{r_1x} +  e^{r_2x}$ and Euler's formula, we know
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
y(x) &= c_1e^{r_1x} +  c_2e^{r_2x} \\
&= c_1e^{2xi} + c_2e^{-2xi} \\
&= c_1(\cos(2x) + i\sin(2x)) +  c_2(\cos(-2x) + i\sin(-2x)) \\
&= c_1(\cos(2x) + i\sin(2x)) + c_2(\cos(2x) - i\sin(2x))
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$
Then, by grouping the sine and cosine terms,
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
y(x) &= c_1(\cos(2x) + i\sin(2x)) + c_2(\cos(2x) - i\sin(2x))\\
&= (c_1 + c_2)\cos(2x) + i (c_1-c_2)\sin(2x)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

Letting $c_1 = \frac{1}{2}$ and $c_2 = \frac{1}{2}$ yields the solution $y_1(x) =\cos(2x)$. Likewise, letting $c_1 = -\frac{1}{2}i$ and $c_2 = \frac{1}{2}i$ yields the solution $y_2(x) = \sin(2x)$. So, by the linear superposition principle, this gives us the general family of solutions
$$
y_c = c_1\cos(2x) + c_2\sin(2x).
$$

From that solution, to find the final particular solution to the IVP, we set $y_c(0) = 1$, and set the derivative of $y_c$ equal to $0$ and solve the system.
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
y_c(0) &= &c_1\cos(0) + &c_2\sin(0) &= 1\\
y_c'(0) &= -2&c_1\sin(0) + 2&c_2\cos(0) &= 0 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

Which gives $c_1 = 1$ and $c_2 = 0$. Substituting these values gives your final solution,
$$
y(x) = \cos(2x)
$$